# MySQL 5.6 : multiple left join leads to incorrectly filled column

Tags: mysql, sql

SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d5b2

I have the following tables under MYSQL 5.6 :

```
users
id | name
---------
1  | John


groups
id | name
---------
1  | admin


constaints
id | name
------------
1  | cons1
2  | cons2


user_to_group
userid | groupid
----------------
1      | 1

constraint_to_group
constrainid | groupid
----------------------
1           | 1

constraint_to_user
constrainid | userid
----------------------
2           | 1
```

The idea is :

- I have *groups* that have constraints.
- *User* can be member or 0..n *groups*
- *Constraints* can also be directly associated to a *user*

I'm trying to build a query that return, for a particular user,

- All its *groups*
- The *constraints* in those *groups*
- The *constraints* directly associated to him

I done the following :

```
SELECT  `users`.*, 
        `constraints`.id as cons_id,
        `constraints`.name as cons_name,
        `groups`.id as group_id,
        `groups`.name as group_name 
FROM `users` 
    LEFT JOIN `user_to_group` 
        ON `user_to_group`.userid=`users`.id 
    LEFT JOIN `groups` 
        ON `groups`.id=`user_to_group`.groupid 
    LEFT JOIN `constraint_to_group` 
        ON `constraint_to_group`.groupid=`user_to_group`.groupid 
    LEFT JOIN `constraint_to_user`
        ON `constraint_to_user`.userid=`users`.id
    LEFT JOIN `constraints` 
        ON (`constraints`.id=`constraint_to_group`.constraintid OR `constraints`.id=`constraint_to_user`.constraintid) 
WHERE `users`.id=1
```

This gets me :

```
|id| name |cons_id|cons_name|group_id|group_name
------------------------------------------------
|1 | john |1      |cons1    |1       |admin
|1 | john |2      |cons2    |1       |admin
```

**My problem :**

*cons2* doesn't come from group *admin*, it's directly associated to the user, so I'd like *group_id* and *group_name* to be set to NULL (or something else) so I can know if the constraint come from a group or is directly associated to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a comparison between `constraint_to_group.constraintid` and `constraints.id`.

So, instead of:

```
    `groups`.id as group_id,
    `groups`.name as group_name
```

use:

```
    IF(`constraint_to_group`.constraintid = `constraints`.id, 
       `groups`.id, NULL) as group_id,
    IF(`constraint_to_group`.constraintid = `constraints`.id, 
        `groups`.name, NULL) as group_name
```

in the `SELECT` clause.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d5b2/10)

Answer (score 0):

You can't set them to NULL. But if you want to get all values of cons_name you can use GROUP_CONCAT function.

```
SELECT  `users`.*, 
        `constraints`.id as cons_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(`constraints`.name) as cons_name,
        `groups`.id as group_id,
        `groups`.name as group_name 
FROM `users` 
    LEFT JOIN `user_to_group` 
        ON `user_to_group`.userid=`users`.id 
    LEFT JOIN `groups` 
        ON `groups`.id=`user_to_group`.groupid 
    LEFT JOIN `constraint_to_group` 
        ON `constraint_to_group`.groupid=`user_to_group`.groupid 
    LEFT JOIN `constraint_to_user`
        ON `constraint_to_user`.userid=`users`.id
    LEFT JOIN `constraints` 
        ON (`constraints`.id=`constraint_to_group`.constraintid OR `constraints`.id=`constraint_to_user`.constraintid) 
WHERE `users`.id=1
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't address my problem. I edited my question so my problem is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Think I would split it to 2 unioned queries. Without doing too much checking, something like this:-

```
SELECT  users.id, 
        users.name,
        constraints.id as cons_id,
        constraints.name as cons_name,
        groups.id as group_id,
        groups.name as group_name 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN user_to_group ON user_to_group.userid = users.id 
LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.id = user_to_group.groupid 
LEFT JOIN constraint_to_group ON constraint_to_group.groupid = user_to_group.groupid 
LEFT JOIN constraints ON constraints.id = constraint_to_group.constraintid
WHERE users.id=1
UNION 
SELECT  users.id, 
        users.name,
        constraints.id as cons_id,
        constraints.name as cons_name,
        NULL as group_id,
        NULL as group_name 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN constraint_to_user ON constraint_to_user.userid = users.id
LEFT JOIN constraints ON constraints.id = constraint_to_user.constraintid
WHERE users.id=1
```